# Django Formset one form in each row

Tags: html, django, django-forms

How to place each form of a formset on a horizontal line, one below the other without using a table?
My html is putting everything on one line.

Any help much appreciated.

**Html**

```
[<div class="form-group row">
<div class="row">
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset.forms %}
{% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
{{ hidden }}
{% endfor %}
<div class="col-sm-2">
    {{ form.logical_operator|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-3">
    {{ form.event|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    {{ form.operator|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
    {{ form.event_value|as_crispy_field }}
</div>
<div class="col-md-1 align-self-center delete-form">
    <button onclick="exclude(this)" type="button"
            title="Excluir"
            class="btn  btn-danger btn-sm">
        <i class="feather icon-trash-2"></i>
    </button>
</div>
{% endfor %}
</div>
</div>
```

[image from screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8M4t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reorganization solved the problem.

Thanks for the help!

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        {% for form in formset %}
        {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
        {{ hidden }}
        {% endfor %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                {{ form.logical_operator|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                {{ form.event|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                {{ form.operator|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                {{ form.event_value|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1 align-self-center delete-form">
                <button onclick="exclude(this)" type="button"
                        title="Excluir"
                        class="btn  btn-danger btn-sm">
                    <i class="feather icon-trash-2"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `</br>` (break line) command:

```html
<h1> HEllo</h1> </br> <h2>How are you</h2>
```

Comment: `</br>` is definitely no valid HTML. Write `<br/>` or better just `<br>`.